# How to add the results from the iteration to new multimap in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11

How to insert  result into a new multimap?? I am trying to search over dictionary container to find keyword given by the user and I need to iterate over the tempCollector to find distinct elements. But, I can't seem to find a way to store the results in tempCollector.

```
//current container with all the data
multimap<string, DictionaryItem> dictionaryContainer;
void search(vector<string> input) {
    if (dictionaryContainer.empty()) {
        cout << "it's empty";
    }
    int inputSize = input.size();
    string tempKeyword = input[0];
    //need to copy or insert the value and keys to the tempCollector
    multimap<string, DictionaryItem>tempCollector;       
    //iteration to find keyword; want to store the result in tempCollector
    auto its = dictionaryContainer.equal_range(tempKeyword);
    for (multimap<string, DictionaryItem>::iterator itr =its.first; itr != its.second; itr++) {
        itr->second.print();          
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to copy the whole `its` range:

```
tempCollector.insert(its.first, its.second);
```

If you want to copy each element:

```
for (auto itr =its.first; itr != its.second; itr++) {
    if (condition) {
        tempCollector.emplace(tempKeyword, itr->second);
        //or
        tempCollector.insert(*itr);
        //or
        tempCollector.emplace(tempKeyWord, DictionaryItem(...));
    }
}
```

Keep in mind (multi)map handles pairs of key/values as `std::pair<Key,T>` (aka `value_type`).
The [multimap::insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/insert) method assumes you've already constructed the pair(s) to insert, while [multimap::emplace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/emplace) will build them for you.